# rearrange elements in a List using Scheme

Tags: list, scheme

I am trying to write a code using SCHEME that takes two arguments, for example '(2 1 3) & '(a b c) and gives a list '(b a c). My code is not working either recursive or iterative. Any help!!

```
(define project 
(lambda (list1 list2 list3 n b index)
(define n (length(list1)))
   (let ((i n))
     (for-each (i)
        (cond 
            ((null? list1) (display "empty"))
            (else
                (define n (car list1))
                (define index (- n 1)) 
                (define b (list-ref list2 index)) 
                (define list3 (cons list3 b)) 
                (define list1 (cdr list1)) 
                list3 ))))))
```

Comment: It would improve the readability of the code that you posted if it was correctly indented. All major Scheme development environments have a functionality that does it automatically.

Comment: i have copied the indented code a few times but keeps getting worse. PS unable to upload a snapshot. :/

Comment: Gah there are tabs in spaces in here too D: D:

Comment: In Emacs: 'Meta-X untabify'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define (rearrange order l)
  (cond ((number? order) (rearrange (list order) l))
        ((list?   order) (map (lambda (num) (list-ref l (- num 1))) order))
        (else 'bad-order)))
```

If you need order to be 'complex' (like `'(1 (2 3) 4)`) then use this:

```
(define (listify thing)
  (cond ((null? thing) '())
        ((pair? thing) (apply append (map listify thing)))
        (else (list thing))))

> (listify 10)
(10)
> (listify '(1 (2 3) 4))
(1 2 3 4)
>
```

and then

```
(define (rearrange order l)
  (map (lambda (num) (list-ref l (- num 1)))
       (listify order)))
```

Comment: any idea on how to resolve for : order = '(2 (1 3) 4) & list= '(a b c d) - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that handles arbitrarily-nested lists: first, a `nested-map` that is like `map` but handles nested lists:

```
(define (nested-map func tree)
  (if (list? tree)
      (map (lambda (x)
             (nested-map func x))
           tree)
      (func tree)))
```

Then, we create a mapper to use with it (using `list-ref` if the list is shorter than 16 elements, otherwise copying to a vector first for better scalability):

```
(define (rearrange indices lst)
  (define mapper (if (< (length lst) 16)
                     (lambda (i)
                       (list-ref lst (- i 1)))
                     (let ((vec (list->vector lst)))
                       (lambda (i)
                         (vector-ref vec (- i 1))))))
  (nested-map mapper indices))
```

Notice how, after the mapper is defined, the function is simply a single call to `nested-map`. Easy! :-D

Comment: Thanks so much. you ppl are amazing. whats the good way of doing error handling in scheme. i have looked up display & ~r for messages, bt didnt work.

Comment: @farey Most Scheme implementations provide an `error` function for that.

Comment: what if the input list has a sublist like (2 1 (2 3) 3)..how to pick the index to arrange output.

Answer (score 0):

First that came to mind:

```
(define (rearrange order symbols)
  (define (element i list)
    (if (= i 1) 
      (car list)
      (element (- i 1) (cdr list))))
  (define (iter order output)
    (if (null? order) 
      output
      (iter (cdr order) 
            (append output (list (element (car order) symbols))))))
  (iter order '()))
```

Better solution:

```
(define (rearrange order symbols)
  (define (nth-element i list)
    (if (= i 1)
      (car list)
      (nth-element (- i 1) (cdr list))))
  (map (lambda (x) (nth-element x symbols)) order))
```

Comment: @user2523987 First function is too much heavy, second should be better.

Comment: You realise that `nth-element` is a built-in function called `list-ref`, right?

Comment: better indeed but what is happening there. :O is there a way i pass a number as first argument and it picks that element from the list (using same function). like (rearrange 2 '(a b)) ---> 'b (its like a list-ref but i don know how to give an argument that function accepts as num or list)

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young Yep, there is a moment here - `list-ref` starts elements numeration from 0, but OP requested numeration from 1. Probably there is a way of using `list-ref` for this purpose. I will think about this.

Comment: @someguy Just subtract 1 from all your arguments to `list-ref`. :-)

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young - exactly =).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple version for un-nested lists:

```
(define (arrange idx lst)
  (map (lambda (i) (list-ref lst i)) idx))

(arrange '(1 0 2) '(a b c))
=> '(b a c)
```

If you need to use nested lists, flatten comes in handy:

```
(define (arrange idx lst)
  (map (lambda (i) (list-ref lst i)) (flatten idx)))

(arrange '(1 (0 2)) '(a b c))
=> '(b a c)
```

Note that I use 0-based indexes, as is the custom in Scheme.