# Rearrange a list given a list of indices

Tags: scheme, lisp

```
(rearrange-this '(4 (4 2) 1) '(a b c d)) -> (d (d b) a)
```

So I need this to recurse into the sub-lists and rearrange those.

```
(define (rearrange-this list1 list2) ;Initial function 
(rearrange-r list1 list2 (count list1) '() list1))

;list 1 holds numbers, list2 hold letters 

(rearrange-this '(4 3 2 1) '( a b c d )) ;-> outputs (d c b a)
(rearrange-this '(2 3 4 1 3 2 1 4) '(a b c d)) ;-> outputs (b c d a c b a d)
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17319737/124319

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use higher order functions whenever possible. The most important ones for list operations are: `map`, `fold`, `filter`, and `list-tabulate`. Learning these will save so much time.

`map` is incredibly useful in this situation. I used it to write a `deep-map` function which delves into sublists and applies an operation to the objects within, although it will not work if you want to map lists to something else since `deep-map` will delve into those lists. You would have to wrap such lists in something to make the `list?` check fail.

After writing deep-map, I use it with `list-ref` to select the appropriate element from `value-list` and replace the number in `arrangement`.

```
(define (deep-map operator deep-list)
    (map
        (lambda (element)
            (if (list? element)
                (deep-map operator element)
                (operator element)))
        deep-list))

(define (rearrange-this arrangement value-list)
    (deep-map
        (lambda (element)
            (list-ref value-list element))
        arrangement))
```

Here is a quick test of the code. Note that unlike your code, the list positions start at 0. You could `map` the input arrangement list if you want to have input references starting at 1. I will leave that as an exercise to you.

```
> (rearrange-this '(3 2 (1 0)) '(a b c d))
;Value 16: (d c (b a))
```